# Doctrine Production Cache with ZF2

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, memcached

I'm currently preparing some software to go into production and I wanted to check that my settings would be optimized but when I run the following command, I'm receiving the following information:

```
php index.php orm:ensure-production-settings
Metadata Cache uses a non-persistent cache driver, Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache.
```

I've also tried the above command with `-vvv` but the output is the same

I began reviewing my code and I cannot find where I am using any ArrayCache.

Here is my [current configuration](https://gist.github.com/diemuzi/1b4f2eeb81f30fc26c43)

I know it's working as I can check the keys in the Memcached system and I can see the performance gains as well. Based on the documentation I've found online I can only find where Doctrine is recommended to have production cache with APC.

I'm currently running PHP 5.6.4 with the latest ZF2 2.3.3 and the latest Doctrine 2. This would make APC unavailable of course.

I'm curious if there is something I am missing or could do so that when I run the `orm:ensure-production-settings` command it assures me that Doctrine Cache is good to go for production?

Perhaps Doctrine only likes APC for optimum cache...

Answer (score 1):

Check your module order.

Your config from module.config.php gets get overwritten my the DoctrineModule.

Check your application.config.php and that it's order is like:

```
return [
'modules' => [
    'DoctrineModule',
    'DoctrineORMModule',

    //YOUR_MODULES_HERE! -> after DoctrineModule
]
];
```

Comment: Actually that's how I have it. The DocrineModule and DoctrineOrmModule are before another module I have called OTDatabase which is where I have my Entities and my configuration for doctrine setup.

Comment: Dump your complete config and check if its all in...SEE CODE in index.php                          <?php // Run the application!
$app = Zend\Mvc\Application::init($appConfig);
var_dump($app->getConfig());
exit();
$app->run();